# issue styling bootstrap navbar when collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, header, styles, navbar

I am using the below css in my code to achieve a transparent white navbar but after collapsing menu in mobile version background style doesn't work. please help me to overcome this issue. i tried most of the solutions found in other questions

```
#header_wrapper {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.82);
}

.header_box {
    position: relative;
}

.header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:transparent;  
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    }
.header.active {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.82);
}
.logo {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.res-nav_click {
    display: none;
}
```

/* Nav Styles
---------------------------------*/

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar {
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    min-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #000;
}

.navStyle {
    float: right;
}

.navStyle ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top:25px;
}

.navStyle ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.navStyle ul li:first-child {
    /*margin:0px;*/;
}

.navStyle ul li:last-child {
    margin: 0 0 0 23px;
}

.navStyle ul li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #222222;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.navStyle ul li a:hover {
    color: #ffc000;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
}

.navStyle > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffc000;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffc000;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffc000;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navStyle > li.active > a,
.navStyle > li.active > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ED5441;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header id="header_wrapper" class="header active border">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header_box">
      <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" id="nav-toggle" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        </div>
        <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse navStyle">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainNav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#" class="scroll-link hidden-xs">Home</a>
              <a href="#" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#about" class="scroll-link hidden-xs">About Us</a>
              <a href="#about" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#products" class="scroll-link hidden-xs">Products</a>
              <a href="#products" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Products</a>
              </li>
                <li><a href="#services" class="scroll-link hidden-xs">Services</a>
                <a href="#services" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Services</a>
                </li>
              <li><a href="#group" class="scroll-link hidden-xs">Group</a>
              <a href="#group" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Group</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#careers" class="scroll-link hidden-xs">Careers</a>
              <a href="#careers" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Career</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll-link hidden-xs">Contact Us</a>
              <a href="#contact" class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
     </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

http://globaltrendz.com/blackandgreen/   please refer this one by changing header-wrapper bgcolor opactiy. like this one what i need

Comment: Can we please have the full code?

Comment: I am afraid this is not enough information to solve your question - your header most probably behaves differently on smaller resolutions but there is no way how to find how from this code.

Comment: it works fine with desktop version

Comment: Link to your website? so that I can open on my mobile and desktop.

Comment: www.globaltrendz.com/uptime

Comment: Its working perfectly fine on my mobile. its a support issue. What mobile and browser are you using for testing?

Comment: which one you are using sir

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/UwG9hcN.jpg  Check this.

Comment: LG G2 mobile and chrome browser. Is this your desired output?

Comment: @javed sir the problem is bgcolor style of the menu items in mobile view,

Comment: @UmerJaved sasi wants background colour in menu when its expands

Comment: navbar works fine but i have proble with custom styling, i need the menu item bg too same as navbar bg

Comment: @srinivas yes sir thats what i want

Comment: pls check my ans, i have posted below

Comment: Just copy paste the code I posted and it should work. I have tested it already.

Comment: Now check my answer. I understood your problem now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want mobile navbar after 765px so you need to use a media query on that.

Add this at the end of your css file:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 765px){
    .navStyle ul{
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.82) !important; //important //because you have inline styles.
    }
}
```

Here's the output:
[image: 'image']

Comment: i only need the bg color for header-wrapper and menu items on toggle

Comment: what's the problem? did you copy pasted the code? i forgot to write opening brackets.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now check. This is what you wanted?

Comment: i put the brackets correctly , look at that url the conatainer bgcolor makes it look odd from header-wrapper bg

Comment: sir check this one http://imgur.com/zwGuHCK the above output which i need with bgcolor spread 100% width.

Comment: I have updated Once more and now I understand your problem.

Comment: sir i included the above updated css of yours but its not working, can you please submit a fiddle link..   or what are the major changes you done in css

Comment: There must be some styles that are over riding the media queries.

Comment: Try adding !important after position fixed and left 0 too

Comment: got solution sir but applying the style to navbar-inverse

Comment: It may create issues in other cases and code will get very difficult to maintain.

Comment: I gave you the solution and it was working perfectly fine. There may be any styling over riding so didn't work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

got the solution by applying below styles

```
   .navbar-inverse {
    background-color: rgba(222,222,222,0.84);
    border-color: transparent;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
}

.navStyle ul {
```

background-color: rgba(222,222,222,0.84);
}

Comment: These are the styles suggested by me so it helped. I'm glad that I helped. :)

Comment: If javed's answer solve your issue. Please accept/mark it as answer by clicking on right symbol

Comment: @ketan Thanks Ketan :)

Comment: @javed :p  but different element

Comment: sry just kidding @javed (y) actually i reffered the screenshot and apply it to my code when i applied that media query it brings truncated bg for menu so i work with every element one by one in developertools